# Adding existing project as reference with packages, references fail

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have an existing project that uses several external packages that are included through the Visual Studio NuGet interface.  Let's call this project `Existing`

In a separate project, I want to add that project as a reference.  Let's call this project `Separate`.

I go to `Separate` and I right click on the Solution in Solution Explorer, and click "Add -> Existing project".  This successfully adds `Existing` to `Separate`.  I then right click on `Existing` and click build.  This causes NuGet to get all of the packages.

However, after that happens all of the references are broken in `Existing` ... they all have the yellow triangle over them.  If I look at the file system, they were successfully downloaded in to `Separate\packages`.

Why can't Visual Studio find the references?  It installed them.

Comment: Was the Existing project in a different solution before? So the packages directory was different so the hint paths to the references are no longer correct?

Comment: Correct, existing is part of a different solution. What are you suggesting I do, then?

Comment: Because once I add it to the new project, shouldn't it obtain a new packages directory?

Comment: No. NuGet does not work like that. The hintpaths are created when the NuGet package assemblies are referenced. You will probably want to create a NuGet.Config file and set the repositoryPath if you want to share the project between two solutions. Or if this is not the case then you can just reinstall the NuGet packages. You should be able to do this from the Package Manager Console with the Update-Package -reinstall command. Just make sure everything is under version control in case things do not work as you expect.

Comment: I also am having this problem. I wonder if there is a way to have the SolutionDir specified as a variable in the HintPath. And I feel that this should be handled automatically.